# How can I add another level to this responsive horizontal nav?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-nav

I am trying to build a responsive navigation for a website with an extra level. How would I update the following html/css/javascript to achieve this? I know this is a big ask but I am hoping someone out there knows the answer. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Resposive Multi Level Horizontal Nav?</title>
    <!--nav styles-->
    <style>
        .show
        {
            display: block;
        }
        nav
        {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
            font-size: 100%;
            color: #252525;
            border-bottom: 4px solid #0069d4;
            border-top: 4px solid #0069d4;
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        ul
        {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        li
        {
            display: inline;
        }
        a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
        }
        li a
        {
            height: 60px;
            line-height: 60px;
            float: left;
            display: block;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 0 20px;
            color: #252525;
        }
        li a:hover
        {
            background-color: #0069d4;
            color: #fff;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
        }

        #i-nav
        {
            display: none;
            float: right;
            padding: 20px 20px;

        }
        @media (max-width: 1024px)
        {
            nav
            {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            ul
            {
                width: 100%;
                display: none;
            }
            li a
            {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #i-nav
            {
                display: block;

            }
        }
    </style>
    <!--google fonts-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--font awesome-->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div><a id="i-nav" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#0069d4;"></i></a></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOMEPAGE</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a>
                <!-- add extra level here
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Program 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Program 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Program 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Program 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Program 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                -->
            <li>
            <li><a href="#">MEMBERSHIP</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">NEWS</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a><li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- script to toggle mobile menu -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#i-nav').click(function(){
                $('ul').toggleClass('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I didn't attempt writing the submenu because I had no idea where to start. I did include what I already had though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am feeling charitable today ...but in the future please try making a code by yourself and then post here if it doesn't work after a few attempts

**check here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/u4hpnv5L/)**

gave a class `.submenu` to the second level `ul`

in the future i suggest not using `float:left` on `li a` , but use `inline-block` on top level `li` and `block` on submenu `li`

css code added :

```
ul.submenu { 
  position:absolute;
  top:100%; 
  display:none
}
ul.submenu li a { 
   display:block;
   float:none
}
nav li { 
   display:inline-block;
}
ul.submenu li { 
   display:block;
}
ul li:hover ul.submenu { 
   display:block
}
nav li  { 
   position:relative
}
```

**also for mobile menu : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/u4hpnv5L/2/)**

code added to media query :

```
ul.submenu { 
        position:relative;
        top:0%; 
        display:block;
        }
ul.submenu li { 
         display:block;
         }
ul.submenu li a{ 
          float:left;
          width:100%;
    }
```

in the future don't use `line-height` and also `height` on `li a` ;

and plus. in the future . **PROVIDE AN EXAMPLE OF WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED FOR YOUR SPECIFIC PROBLEM !**

otherwise you will get comments like the one from Paulie. and you won't get answers.

let me know if this code did the trick

Comment: This doesn't work when the menu displays vertically for mobile.

Comment: well i've answered your initial question, even though you didn't supply any code that you've made in an attempt to solve your problem. so for mobile. try it by yourself and let me see the code you've tried

Comment: Did you not read the code with the question i just sent? All the code is there. Copy it to a html file and you can see what I mean.

Comment: i meant a code for your specific problem. eg. a code for the mobile submenu that you have tried and it's not working

Comment: the code is embedded in the html which is attatched to the question

Comment: you mean that little script with toggle class ? . i meant a css code for SUBMENU . i don't see anything like that there . but anyway . i will answer your question. i will edit my answer with the final solution

Comment: thanks. that solved it :) just one other question, you wouldn't know how to add a button to hide and show the submenu in the mobile view?